# Why jQuery is not working with DataTable?

Tags: javascript, datatable

I want to create a new datatable but when I try to add jQuery "click()" function its not really working.
For Example:

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable();
$('.example').on('click', function(){
    alert("This is not working");
})
```

This will not work.
But if I create a drawcallback function:

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "drawCallback": function() {
        $('.example').on('click', function(){
            alert("This will work");
        })
    }
});
```

Its working perfectly. Where I make a mistake? How can I make functions work without calling drawcallback?
Thank you!
Have a nice day!

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Use [event delegation](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events#event-delegation) since your `.example` is created dynamically : `$('#dataTable').on('click', '.example', () => alert("This is not working"))` Your current working example could set a handler multiple times